# On python with numpy/scipy len() cProfile result

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cprofile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

I have using `cProfile` to find out what method spent me most of the time on my python code, here is an output after sorting for "percall":

I found that the method `len()` spent me most of the time:

```
53515/533   330 930 0   940 00{len}
```

However, I know that `len()` call would call the python object `__len__()` method, how do I know what python class/object spent me the most?

I was using python 2.6.5 and run my script using:

```
python -m cProfile myscript.py
```

In fact, my code will use `python-numpy`, `scipy` and work on doing numerical optimization using Newton's method. I believe the calculation of the gradient of the objective function spent me most of the time and would like to find out the reason why it spent so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cProfile gives you for each function two times: the total time spent inside this function including subcalls and the total time spent inside this function excluding subcalls. To detect bottle necks you typically consider the biggest costs according to those two metrics.

In your case I would look for functions calling len a lot and see if I can store the value somewhere to avoid unecessary calls.